# How to increase Dictionary size in gensim while making Corpus?

Tags: python, dictionary, gensim

I was making a corpus using the command

```
background_corpus = TextCorpus('wiki.en.text')
```

This is an over 10 GB file so while making this Corpus and it adding to a dictionary it gives this

```
adding document #820000 to Dictionary(2000000 unique tokens: [u'tripolitan', u'ftdna', u'soestdijk', u'billycorgan', u'olmsville']...)

discarding 31072 tokens: [(u'vnsas', 1), (u'ezequeel', 1), (u'trapeztafel', 1), (u'pubsub', 1), (u'gyvenimas', 1), (u'gilibrand', 1), (u'catfaced', 1), (u'beuningan', 1), (u'moodadi', 1), (u'nocaster', 1)]...

keeping 2000000 tokens which were in no less than 0 and no more than 830000 (=100.0%) documents
```

Hence its discarding the new tokens as its maximum size is 2000000. Is there anyway I can not limit on the size of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explaination https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html. The argument `prune_at` is setted to `2000000`, depending on the function you are using you can change it to `None` to avoid the problem of discarding.

EDIT: in gensim/corpora/dictionary.py (line 45 in the current release on the init function) you can set `prune_at = None` or set your own limit (5000000 for example with `prune_at = 5000000`).